# word for a person who tries to gimmick/gamify the system/process

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

word for someone who just tries to gamify/gimmick the system, who is not focused on searching for the firm/fundmental rules and the big picture, playing the little games, juggler.

like a salesman who interested in finding trickery for a short-sight quick rewards.

in my mind, it would be "gamifier" but it is not a legit English word

Comment: You should reread the [definition of *gamify*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gamification).  It does **not** mean *to treat something like a game*.  It means *to make an activity more enjoyable by adding game-like elements*.  For example, *the salesperson who makes the most phone calls in a day earns 10 points; the first person to earn 50 points wins a plastic trophy.*

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is an

> **opportunist**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A person who takes advantage of opportunities as and when they arise, regardless of planning or principle.
>
> *Not necessarily incompetent, they are opportunists who seize the chance to make lots of money for doing relatively little work.*
>
> *There are opportunists who think of Diwali as a way to make a buck and sell it as a colorful commodity on the market.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/opportunist).

Answer (score 0):

**manipulator** (n.)

> If you describe someone as a manipulator, you mean that they
> skillfully control events, situations, or people, often in a way that
> other people disapprove of. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/manipulator)

**manipulate** (v.)

> To manage or utilize skillfully
>
> To control or play upon by artful, unfair, or insidious means
> especially to one's own advantage
>
> To change by artful or unfair means so as to serve one's purpose
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulator)

---

> A notorious currency **manipulator**, **gaming the system** to favor
> Chinese exports, it is also the largest holder of American debt among
> foreign nations, which makes confrontations over currency and other
> economic issues tricky. [David Axelrod; *Believer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Believer/QuzYCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=manipulator%20gaming%20the%20system&pg=PA413&printsec=frontcover)

> **Gaming the system** refers to the intentional **manipulation** of the data to make the reports look more respectable. [G. Plenert and J.
> Plenert; *Strategic Excellence in the Architecture, Engineering, and
> Construction Industries*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Strategic_Excellence_in_the_Architecture/fmRRDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=manipulator%20gaming%20the%20system&pg=PT165&printsec=frontcover)

> This herd constitutes the owners of trusts and combines.
> By **hoodwinking and trickery**, the herder (the arch-**manipulator**) cheats them out of the control of those trusts and combines. [*Machinists' Monthly Journal*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Machinists_Monthly_Journal/FfHNAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=manipulator%20cheat&pg=PA1055&printsec=frontcover)